# How to convert Mobile Map Package(.mmpk) file to File Geodatabase(.gdb) format?

Tags: converters, geospatial, arcgis, qgis, geo

Hello Dear Residents,

There is a map data with the extension .mmpk in my hand to use the map offline. For me to be able to use the map, the data format should be in .gdb format. Eventhough that file can be successfully opened and be viewed in ArcGIS Pro, I couldn't find directly converting method from .mmpk to .gdb which is supported by Esri in ArcGIS Pro.

ChatGPT couldn't properly help me to convert the file extension.

Does anyone know how to achieve **converting .mmpk file to .gdp file** in ArcGIS Pro App or in another app?